# add an img tag to the output generated by xslt

Tags: c#, html, xml, image, xslt

I am converting XML to Html using XSLT. I have to insert an image tag in the html file generated. I want to add the value of its "src" attribute from "href" attribute of content. But the "src" attribute comes out to be blank. I have following as a part of my XML

```
 <body>
      <sec id="ch1.1">
        <title>INTRODUCTION 1</title>
        <p>The trends of increased functionality, improved performance, reduced size and increased complexity continue to evolve in the automotive electronics market. New system architectures are providing the performance and memory capability necessary to keep up with the hardware performance and software growth required by the automotive market trends. All of this technology growth implies a higher product cost and increased engineering effort required to develop these new products.</p>
        <p>
        <fig id="F22" position="float">
        <label>FIG. 2.7</label>
        <caption><p>Major components of internal combustion engines.</p></caption>
        <graphic content-type="figure" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="R-396_fig0021"/>
        </fig>
        </p>
        <p>In order to meet all of the technical and business objectives, corporations must manage project development cost by increasing the productivity and efficiency of engineering activities, reducing developmental spend rates, shortening product development times, and ensuring that the end objectives for product performance and delivery are met to schedule. Making the economic problem more complex, corporate globalization has moved at an unprecedented rate to capture and expand market share, better serve global customers and improve corporate efficiencies. This global movement has produced a significant amount of economic benefit to the corporate business metrics.</p>
```

and i have following xslt

```
    <xsl:for-each select="body/sec">
                <p>
                  <h1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                  </h1>
                  <br></br>
                  <xsl:for-each select="p">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    <xsl:if test="fig">
                     <img alt="{fig/id}" src="{fig/graphic/content/@xlink:href}" style="position:{fig/@position}">


                </img>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="fig/caption/p"/></p>                        
</xsl:if>

                  </xsl:for-each>
```

i want the following output

```
<p>The trends of increased functionality, improved performance, reduced size and increased complexity continue to evolve in the automotive electronics market. New system architectures are providing the performance and memory capability necessary to keep up with the hardware performance and software growth required by the automotive market trends. All of this technology growth implies a higher product cost and increased engineering effort required to develop these new products.</p><p><img src="../images/R-396_fig0021" style="position:float" alt="Fig 2.7"/>Major components of internal combustion engines.</p><p>In order to meet all of the technical and business objectives, corporations must manage project development cost by increasing the productivity and efficiency of engineering activities, reducing developmental spend rates, shortening product development times, and ensuring that the end objectives for product performance and delivery are met to schedule. Making the economic problem more complex, corporate globalization has moved at an unprecedented rate to capture and expand market share, better serve global customers and improve corporate efficiencies. This global movement has produced a significant amount of economic benefit to the corporate business metrics.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can adapt this stylesheet to yours. As much as possible, avoid doing `xsl:for-each` everytime. Use template matching as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" exclude-result-prefixes="xlink"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sec|caption/p">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sec/title">
        <h1><xsl:apply-templates/></h1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fig">
        <img src="../images/{graphic/@xlink:href}" style="position:float" alt="{label}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="caption/p"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```